# How to check if array attribute from JSON object is empty?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I've this kind of JSON object :

```
sections: 
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "title":"Description du projet",
        "content":[
            {
                label:'Type de projet',
                type:'select',
                values:[
                    {
                        label:'Achat',
                        options:[
                            {
                                label:'Neuf'
                            },
                            {
                                label:'Neuf + travaux'
                            },
                            {
                                label:'Ancien'
                            },
                            {
                                label:'Ancien + travaux'
                            },
                            {
                                label:'Terrain'
                            },
                            {
                                label:'Terrain + construction'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

And I would like to check if the **"options"** array is define or not in order to build different component in each case.

Is it possible ? If yes can you tell me how ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `if(myObject.sections[0].content[0].values[0].options) { }`

Comment: so you have multiple `sections` in your component, that contain multiple `content` blocks, where some might represent `select` boxes, wich probably will have defined one ore more `options`. And you component depends on that? Wether some select box in some content block in some section has or has not an option?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's my situtation and I use that to build my React components. Is there a problem for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate each array from "sections" until "values", then we will do the checking there. See these code:

```
sections.forEach(section =>{
  section.content.forEach(c => {
    c.values.forEach(value =>{
      if (!value.options) {
        // "options" array is undefined.
        return;
      }

      // "options" array is defined, build different components here.
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash to do all the undefined or exists checks. Check out the library [here](https://lodash.com/docs)

Coming to your question, using lodash I'd do something like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
let options = _.get(a, ['sections','0','content', '0', 'values', '0', 'options']);
if(!_.isUndefined(options)){
    //do your stuff
}
```

You can do this in many ways using lodash. You can also get default value  back if the path doesn't exist.